# article view override let content plugin not loading in joomla

Tags: php, joomla, joomla2.5

Just a quick question, I have overridden my article view on the frontend to meet my requirements. Now I installed a content plugin to display facebook like and share icons in the article view but this plugin is not visible in the article view. I have already ennabled the plugin from the backend. I presumed that the problem arises because of overriding the default article view in joomla.

Any idea how to load this content plugin to this overridden article view (as it should happen normally)?

Answer (score 2):

Did you include the events the way the jooomla core does?

```
<?php if (!$params->get('show_intro')) : echo $this->item->event->afterDisplayTitle; endif; ?>
    <?php echo $this->item->event->beforeDisplayContent; ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not cleared whether installed plugin works fine if you don't override view. Then there must be problem with plugin. I have done same thing for my one of the project & thats works fine for Joomla 2.5. Check plugin forum to get more info.

Answer (score 1):

What Elin said is right, please refer your override weather you have echoed that plug-in line

```
<?php echo $this->item->event->beforeDisplayContent; ?>
```

in your other project where you have done the same thing, that template might have that line and in your current project, that line must be missing. Nothing more.